# Jira - Submit portal form using Python

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

I'm looking for a way to submit a portal form using Python. For example I have a form at https://instance.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/1/group/1/create/1

I can authenticate using email:token with or without the jira module and also create issues. However I want to create issues by submitting the form on the portal. Is there a way to do this using python? Can be with or without using the jira module

For reference here is the code I have to authenticate and create issues using the jira module:

```
from jira import JIRA

jira_connection = JIRA(basic_auth=('email@email.com', 'tokenxxxxxxxxx'), server="https://myinstance.atlassian.net")

issue_dict = {
'project': {'key': 'TEST'},
'summary': 'Testing script',
'description': 'Testing script',
'issuetype': {'name': 'Service Request'},
}

new_issue = jira_connection.create_issue(fields=issue_dict)
print(new_issue)
```

And here is the code without using the jira module:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://myinstance.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/myself"

headers = {
"Authorization": "Basic <base64 encoded email:token>",
"Accept": "application/json"
}

response = requests.request( "GET", url, headers=headers )

print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": ")))
```

This is the POST I'm trying but getting a 400:

```
jira_load={
    "fields": {
        "description": {"version":1,"type":"doc","content":[{"type":"paragraph","content":[{"type":"text","text":"Test description"}]}]},
        "summary": "Test summary",
        "project": {
            "key": "TEST"
        },
        "issuetype": {
            "name": "IT Help"
        },
    }
}
url = 'https://instance.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/1/create/1'
r = requests.post(url, data=jira_load)
print ("HERE's the JSON RESPONSE\n\n ", r.status_code, r.headers)
print ("The response content is\n\n", r.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Jira Service Management**, you can use its REST API: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/service-desk/rest/intro/#jira-cloud-platform-apis to operate on Portal issues (Create - https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/service-desk/rest/api-group-request/#api-rest-servicedeskapi-request-post). I suppose that this JIRA library is open source and maybe does not have SD operations (not sure what lib it is).